# "-vf crop" doesn't work on FFMpeg hevc_nvenc

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, cuda, h.265, nvenc

This command line downscales fine my 4k video:

```
$ ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=1920:1080:interp_algo=bicubic -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 1M -bufsize 5M -maxrate 1M -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv
```

But if I try to crop the black bars with `-crop=3840:1608:0:276`, **they remains** on video file destination:

```
$ ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input_video.mkv -vf -crop=3840:1608:0:276,scale_cuda=1920:804:interp_algo=bicubic -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 1M -bufsize 5M -maxrate 1M -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crop` filter is executed on the CPU, but the decoded frames are in the memory of the GPU device.
For using `crop` (CPU) filter, we may use `hwdownload,crop...,hwupload`... (download the frames to the system memory, apply cropping in the CPU, and upload to the GPU for encoding).
But it's inefficient...
We like to look for GPU "device filter" like `crop_cuda`, but there is none.
Luckily `hevc_cuvid` decoder and `h264_cuvid` decoder support `-crop` argument.

Note that this is a decoder feature, and not a video filter.

---

Assume the video codec of `input_video.mkv` is HEVC (H.265), we may use the following command:

`ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v hevc_cuvid -crop 276x552x0x0 -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=1920:804:interp_algo=bicubic -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 1M -bufsize 5M -maxrate 1M -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv`

In case the input codec is H.264, replace `hevc_cuvid` with `h264_cuvid`.

---

Executing `ffmpeg -h decoder=hevc_cuvid` (for help), tells us that the `-crop` syntax is:
`Crop (top)x(bottom)x(left)x(right)`.
That means, number of top rows to remove, number of bottom rows to remove, number of left, and number of right columns to remove.

---

Testing:

Create synthetic H.265 encoded input (for testing):
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=3840x2160:rate=1:duration=100 -c:v libx265 input_video.mkv`

Execute the command:
`ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v hevc_cuvid -crop 276x552x0x0 -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=1920:804:interp_algo=bicubic -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 1M -bufsize 5M -maxrate 1M -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv`

The output resolution is 1920x804.
[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks again, my friend @Rotem. Works fine with HEVC but not with H.264 . I try with this command line: `ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -crop 276x276x0x0 -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=1920:804:interp_algo=bicubic:format=yuv420p -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -tune hq -b:v 5181k -bufsize 5M -maxrate 5181k -qmin 0 -g 250 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode middle -temporal-aq 1 -rc-lookahead 20 -i_qfactor 0.75 -b_qfactor 1.1 -an -sn output_video.mkv` with these errors:

Comment: `[matroska,webm @ 0x5613fb757ec0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none, 3840x2160): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options`

Comment: `[h264_mp4toannexb @ 0x5613fc4e86c0] Global extradata truncated, corrupted stream or invalid MP4/AVCC bitstream
[vist#0:0/h264 @ 0x5613fb7a70c0] [dec:h264_cuvid @ 0x5613fb7a6f40] Error while opening decoder: Invalid data found when processing input
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 0x5613fb7b2a80] Error initializing a simple filtergraph
Error opening output file output_video.mkv.
Error opening output files: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: Please try synthetic video first: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=3840x2160:rate=1:duration=100 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p input_video.mkv` and `ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -crop 276x276x0x0 -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=1920:804:interp_algo=bicubic -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr -rc-lookahead 20 -b:v 1M -bufsize 5M -maxrate 1M -g 250 -an -sn output_video.mkv`.

Comment: According to the error messages, I think that your input file is not H.264 encoded video. You may check the codec information using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), or FFprobe.

Comment: Exactly. My input video is HEVC but I want to convert it to H.264 1080p with CUDA and h264_nvenc.

Comment: Wait a minute... I understand now!: `ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v hevc_cuvid -crop 276x276x0x0 -i input_video.mkv -vf scale_cuda=1920:804:interp_algo=bicubic -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -tune hq -b:v 5181k -bufsize 5M -maxrate 5181k -qmin 0 -g 250 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode middle -temporal-aq 1 -rc-lookahead 20 -i_qfactor 0.75 -b_qfactor 1.1 -an -sn output_video.mkv`  **Works fine now!** `h264_cuvid` and `hevc_cuvid` must be same the input video codec. Sorry for my error. Thanks again, @Rotem